# How to preserve user choices between sessions in Google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, hardware-interface

It is possible to access certain types of privileged hardware in Chromium based browsers.

Is there a way to preserve the devices that permission was granted to? Or does it have to be requested every time?

Bluetooth and SerialPorts are examples.
[image: example of privileged hardware dialog]

The spec isn't finalised but I wondering if there is a way to record user selection after those dialogs are shown.

The procedure for accessing the port is to request permission from the user, which adds their selection to the list of available ports.

Is there a way to preserve the devices that permission was granted to? or does it have to be requested every time